# Convert Points to Polygons in QGIS

Tags: convert, qgis-2

Is it possible to convert Points into Polygons in QGIS 2.10 Pisa? I just want to create a 1x1m Polygon based on the centroid of each Point.
I tried *Vector > Geometry Tools > Voronoi Polygons* but that is not what I want at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the sounds of it, you want to buffer your points (go Vector->GeoProcessing Tools->Buffer(s)).  Push the 'segments to approximate' up to get a smoother circle.

If you want square buffers, unfortunately the plugin that did that has not been updated to work with QGIS 2.x.  However a work around could be to rasterize your points with a resolution of 1m and then convert the raster to a vector.  The alignment of some of your resultant polygons may be a bit off though as a raster is a regular grid and I assume your points are not aligned to a grid.

If you want a grid do a search as there are a few posts on that subject (hint - look in Vector->Research tools)

Answer (score 4):

Create a virtual text field with WKT (Well Known Text) in the attribute table using field calculator (set the layer editable):
[image: expression to create virtual field]

Save the layer as CSV (right click on the layer name in the legend and Save As...), DO NOT CHECK Add Save File to Map!
[image: Save As dialog]

Load the created CSV file with Add Delimited Text File, and check WKT geometry

[image: Delimited Text Layer parameters]

Finally 'save as' the polygon layer into your favorite format.